# Can we add Zoom In Out feature in highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

[image]

The above chart is highstock so highchart have zoom in feature . Can we get the same feature in highcharts.Please help!!!

Comment: Which type of chart from highchart you are referring. Some chart has ```drilldown``` view.

Comment: I am using step chart.https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=41950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to use `Highstock` source code to be able to enable a navigator with basic `chart` constructor type:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [...]
    }],
    navigator: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aug9L52r/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.enabled